# Unable to send location updates to server because of battery saver mode in MIUI and Battery optimization above Android 8.0

Tags: android

By using alarm manager all works fine.But i don't want to user alarm manager i just want to use location services with broadcast receiver and intent service.i am able to get location updates but i am unable to send them to server.

I have refered :
- https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/background-location- 
  updates-android-o/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#6
- https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background-location- 
  limits
- https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze- 
  standby#whitelisting-cases

Comment: any of links not working

Comment: Nope.if i remove my app from battery saver mode  it works fine. otherwise won't work after killing the app.I cannot even tell each user to remove app from battery saver mode

Comment: link not working...

Comment: Sorry : https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background-location-limits

Comment: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/background-location-updates-android-o/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#6

Comment: anyone have any idea @Mohsinali

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/JobIntentService